# I'm using material ui accordion component and don't want to collapse it unless I click the expandIcon

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using the material ui accordion component and I couldn't find a way to stop the panel from collapsing when clicked. My goal is to open and close the panel only by clicking the icon in the accordionsummery component. I found many ways to stop collapsing by click a checkbox for example, but not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

With default Material-UI package ;

> "No" way

Because, on AccordionSummary there is a context mechanism which watches if that Accordion is expanded and produces isExpanded as a value. You need to manipulate core package code the way you wanted, which is a long haul.

Btw, adding onClick function to ExpandMoreIcon gives infinite loop because of that context.

You can go with [Additional actions](https://material-ui.com/components/accordion/) version of Material-UI accordion and hide the checkbox as only viewing the data.